# How can I return a string value from a function in C++

Tags: c++, string, function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

std::string dispCard(int card)
{
    string textCard = "help";
    //cout << textCard;

    system("pause");
    return textCard;
}

int main()
{
    // Using this area to test functions for now
    cout << dispCard(14);

    return 0;
}
```

Uncommenting the `cout` line actually does display the value. But I cannot return the value in the string.

Honestly, I have no idea why this isn't working. I initially just wanted to use "char" but that doesn't work for some reason.

Visual Studio didn't like:

```
char test;
test = "help";
```

It underlined the "=".

For now, I just want to return a string value from a function. There's more that I need it to do, but this is the main issue right now.

Comment: 1. You need `const char* test = "help` if you need a c-style string
2. I guess you can just do `return std::string("help")` if you would like to return a string.

Comment: What do you mean it is not returning the string? And why do you have a `system("pause")` before returning?

Comment: Pleas test/launch your program within a console/terminal and get rid of that `system("pause");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Uncommenting the cout line actually does display the string. But not returning the string.

Your program [both prints and returns the string](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75eb8e1f0b7e975b), printing it again in `main`. The only problems I can see with your program are:

1. You are using `system("pause")` for no reason.
2. You are not consistent with the use of either the `std::` prefix or importing the namespace. On this regard I highly suggest the `std::` prefix.
3. You are not using the function argument.

---

> I initially just wanted to use "char" but that doesn't work for some reason.

Well, `char`, as the name suggests, can only store 1 characters. In:

```
char test = "help";
```

you are trying to assign 5 characters (4 + `\0`) to an objects who's size can only store 1. That's the reason why your compiler complained.

Comment: 1. Wow, I didn't even notice that... Thanks, it's working fine now. 2. What exactly do you mean by that? I'm a little confused on that. I'd like to use the "using namespace" but I read somewhere else that even if it's there, you have to do the std:: on strings.        3. That sounds like a really big error... But it works perfectly. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to pass an int to your function and get it back in string form. To do this conversion you need something like this:

```
std::ostringstream stm;
stm << yourIntValue;
std::string s(stm.str());
```

or this:

```
char bf[100];
sprintf(bf, "%d", yourIntValue);
std::string s(bf);
```

If you put this snippet in a function then you can also accept an int parameter, convert it to a std::string and return the std::string as others have shown.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to declare return type of function as `std::string` and then return either a string object, something that can implicitly be converted to string object or something that explicitly constructs string object.

Example:

```
std::string foo(){
    return "idkfa"; //return C-style string -> implicitly convertible to string
    return {"idkfa"}; // direct initialization of returning std::string
    return std::string("idkfa"); //return explicitly constructed std::string object
}
```

Also note that C-style strings are of type `char*` (C-style strings are basically an array of `chars`, with last element being `\0`, that is 0).

Answer (score 0):

Your code [works perfectly fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c42b9e30d6ef7901), though the the `system("pause")` is totally redundant and pointless and should be removed. It may in fact be confusing you.